# Can ASP.NET Core deserialization set null in property if all children properties are nulls?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, deserialization, system.text.json

In ASP.NET Core 8, I have the `CreatePerson` Minimal API which receives the JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Peter",
  "residence": {
    "country": null,
    "status": null
  },
}
```

This JSON is mapped to the class `CreatePersonRequest`:

```
public record CreatePersonRequest(
  string name,
  Residence? residence
);

public record Residence(
  string Country,
  string Status
);
```

When the JSON is sent to the `CreatePerson` API, ASP.NET Core deserializes it and instantiates a `CreatePersonRequest` with the `Residence` property instantiated, but with all its child properties (`Country` and `Status`) as nulls.

In this scenario, I want the JSON deserialization to return a `CreatePersonRequest` object with `Residence` property as null.

I tried setting `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`, but it did not work.

```
services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

How could I achieve this?

Edit: My current JSON configuration is:

```
services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower;
options.SerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower;
});
```

Update 1:
I attempted to use `TypeInfoResolver` to set a residence when `Country` and `Status` properties are not null. While this approach works, it necessitates creating a setter for the `Residence` property in the `CreatePersonRequest` class. However, I would prefer to keep `CreatePersonRequest` as an immutable class.

```
public static void IgnoreIfChildrenAreNulls(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
{
  if (typeInfo.Type != typeof(CreatePersonRequest))
    return;
  foreach (var propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
  {
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Residence))
    {
      propertyInfo.Set = (createPersonRequestObject, residenceObject) =>
      {
        var createPersonRequest = (CreatePersonRequest)createPersonRequestObject;
        var residence = (Residence?)residenceObject;
        if (residence is null || (residence.Country is null && residence.Status is null))        
           return;
        // It requires that Residence has a setter
        createPersonRequest.Residence = residence;
      };
    }
  } 
}
```

```
options.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
{
 Modifiers = { CreatePersonEndpoint.IgnoreIfChildrenAreNulls }
};
```

Comment: "I want the JSON deserialization to return a CreatePersonRequest object with Residence property as null" but that's not the same thing at all. You'd need some kind of custom converter to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I mean, this is a quite specific requirement, .NET did not provide this out of the box. You have to create a Custom Converter for that.

```
public class NullToEmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter<Residence>
{
    public override Residence Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            options.Converters.Clear();
            var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Residence>(ref reader, options);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Country) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Status))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return value;
        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Residence value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

And then you have to add this to your JsonDeserializer via JsonSerializerOptions

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NullToEmptyStringConverter());
```

or

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NullToEmptyStringConverter());
});
```

Happy Coding and don't forget to upvote!

PS:
The `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull` option you tried only affects the serialization process, not the deserialization. It tells the serializer to ignore properties with null values when writing JSON, but it doesn’t affect how the deserializer handles null values.

Comment: I tried to implement the NullToEmptyStringConverter, but it results in a loop.

Comment: Due to JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Residence>(ref reader, options) invoking the NullToEmptyStringConverter again and again.

Comment: ahh sorry my fault xD you should not reference the same options in the converter but rather use them without the option of this converter. otherwise this line            " var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Residence>(ref reader, options);" will cause in calling itself (the converter) again

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer

Comment: Thanks, in the NullToEmptyStringConverter class, how could reuse my JsonOptions configurations without recreate them?

Comment: Yes sure I mean you get them as a parameter of this method so you can pass it to the Deserialize method. But You have to remove the converters inside the converter so you don't cause this endless recursion. Call JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Clear() before passing it to the Deserialize method.